# Downloading file in Rails with error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, download

I need to fetch and download file from URL. Users should put this URL and system should download the file. I need a standard practice for it that could handle the errors.

This is my code now:

```
@dl = IO.copy_stream( open( params[:url] ), 'file.txt' )
if( @dl )
    render json: {:status => true, :message => 'downloaded.'}
else
    render json: {:status => true, :message => 'downloaded.'}
end
```

What is the best practices for it and how to handle errors? The file that I want to download normally are about 100KB.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you need to do there :

1/ Use strong params

2/ Your use of Kernel#open with user input is a HUGE security risk there. Don't do that.

3/ Pretty sure you want something like [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files) instead